# how to get page to a specific part of page?

Tags: html, css, razor

I'm trying to create a page where a user clicks on a link on the left and is taking to a specific section on the page.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/uzi002/tuD7J/4) is example. I've added as much of the code I'm using as I can.

Comment: i have also tried  location.hash which also makes the menu disappear

Comment: There are many nicer ways to go about building a navigation menu, but you are pretty close with the core idea. Can you provide a link to the rendered HTML, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your trying to do works with the Id or Name attribute.

To elaborate: The anchor tag that your rendering as the target of where your page needs to go should be:

```
<a id="myId"></a>
```

or

```
<a name="myId"></a>
```

or both..

Comment: i dont understand, i have tried with the name but my menu dissapears

Comment: Leave the menuitem alone. See my edit. For clarity: Im talking about the anchor tag in the part where your rendering your paragraphs

Comment: Can you provide an online testcase somewhere? That way we can also see if there might be any css issues.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uzi002/tuD7J/4/ has an example, ive added as much of the code im using as i can

Answer (score 0):

When you build a link to another part of the page, you need two parts, the link (that you click), and the target (that the page scrolls to).

1. The link's `href` attribute needs to start with a '#'. This signifies that the link is 'internal' to the page, and not another, external page.
2. The target can be either a named anchor `<a name="something"></a>` or an element with an ID: `<div id="something">`. **You don't include the '#' in the name or the ID.**

That's the key part you're missing. Take the '#' off the front of your `<a name="">` values and it will work.

Let us know if that works, and we can help you develop this further: There's a lot more polish you could add, but let's get the basics working first.

Comment: i can see the menu in the page source but not on the page

Comment: @Beginner, I think the remaining issue is a CSS/layout problem. Could you please create a separate question for that? There's a lot of weird stuff in your HTML/CSS, and it might take some work to get to the bottom of it! Thanks.